# How to get sum of each element in first array and each element in second array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to do it using LINQ?

```
var currentSums = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
        currentSums.Add(firstArray[i] + secondArray[j]);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it with Linq? This works and is fine.

Comment: Also, what happens if the arrays are of different length?

Comment: @DavidG Why not? 1 line is better than 4.

Comment: You could put all this code on one line too. Why is 1 line better than 4? Linq can make things slower and less readable.

Comment: @DavidG if in first array will be N elements and in second array will be M elements then in result list should be N*M elements

Comment: "1 line is better than 4." no. _understandable_ code is better than _needlessly complicated_ code.  but the number of lines as a metric for code quality? that's something clueless product managers use, not programmers.

Comment: `firstArray.SelectMany(v1 => secondArray.Select(v2 => v1 + v2)).ToList()`, but I'm with @FranzGleichmann on this. Readability and understandability [sic] trumps linecount.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann OK. Let's pretend that the question is asked with scientific interest

Comment: @Matvey it's scientifically proven that "understandable code" trumps "short code". case closed. also: to satisfy your scientific curiosity,  i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks!

Comment: You can do a cross join in Linq that will give you the same result, but I'm not sure it's a good idea https://dotnetfiddle.net/Omc6Y1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, you could use LINQ, then you have to use `SelectMany` which is often the solution if you want to *linqify* nested loops:

```
List<int> currentSums = firstArray.SelectMany(i1 => secondArray.Select(i2 => i1 + i2)).ToList();
```

But if that is better(more readable) than your approach depends on if you are writing LINQ code in sleep which i doubt. It's not better or faster than the nested loop.